# Filter array of objects based on another object

Tags: javascript, object

Value of typeOfFilters is selected from different component, so in my current component I get value of currency and frequency, but my filter function doesn't iterate over frequency.

I want to add more filters to my filter function. Do tell me how can i simplify this problem?
plans looks like this.

````js
let plans = [

{
    "amount": 6000,
    "currency": "USD",
    "frequency": "MONTH",
    "planId": "plan_L7mrzVML9o6G5c",
    "planName": "computer",
    "provider": "stripe"
},

{
    "amount": 2000,
    "currency": "INR",
    "frequency": "DAY",
    "planId": "plan_KkHkJPEVR7ZA2s",
    "planName": "Platinum",
    "provider": "stripe"
}
]

 

const typeOfFilters = {
 

 currency: ['INR'],
  frequency: ['DAY'],
  provider: "",
  amount: "",
  status: "",
}

   

 const sortedTableArray = plans.filter(function (plan) {
        for (const [f, values] of Object.entries(typeOfFilters)) {
            if (!typeOfFilters[f]) {
                return true;
            }
            if (
                f === "currency" &&
                typeOfFilters["frequency"].indexOf(plan[f]) > -1
            ) {
                return true;
            }
            if (f === "currency" && typeOfFilters[f].indexOf(plan[f]) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
            if (plan[f] === undefined || plan[f] !== typeOfFilters[f]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
 ```
expected output should return the table entry which has the frequency inside typeOfFilter['frequency']
````

Comment: I want to add more filters to my filter function. Do tell me how can i simplify this problem. Thanks

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the plans and expected output

Comment: For inside filter will return the new array try using forEach instead of filter function and in place of typeOfFilters[f] use values it will also work fine.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add some values for  `plans`, `typeOfFilters` and the expected output

Comment: Currently, your `filter` isn't checking for all the filter keys. If the first key is falsy, `if (!typeOfFilters[f]) return true` adds the object in the returned array

Comment: @adiga i commented out the part you mentioned but still it didn't work

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. Please add non-trivial input (more than two entries) and expected output for some filter, and what you get instead.

Comment: Can I ask why you are bothering to return false? If true is not returned, then filter will not retain the object that is being checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're trying to filter the data based on multiple filters and assuming that the individual filter can also have multiple values. For example: if `currency` filter is `['USD', 'INR']` then you're expecting plans of both currency type.

I updated the `typeOfFilters` object as follows so that each filter can have a basic initial state:

```js
const typeOfFilters = {
    "currency": [],
    "frequency": [],
    "provider": [],
    "amount": 0,
    "status": [],
}
```

And based on that here's the final function:

```js
let sortedTableArray = plans.filter(plan => {
    for (let f in typeOfFilters) {
        // Tests for all array type filters
        if (typeOfFilters[f] instanceof Array && typeOfFilters[f].length == 0) {
            continue
        }
        if (typeOfFilters[f] instanceof Array && typeOfFilters[f].indexOf(plan[f]) == -1){
            return false;
        }

        // Test for amount filter
        if (typeof typeOfFilters[f] === "number" && plan[f] < typeOfFilters[f]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but the iteration does not fail. It is just interrupted by your last check:

```
if (plan[f] === undefined || plan[f] !== typeOfFilters[f]) {
   return false;
}
```

More specifically by:

```
plan[f] !== typeOfFilters[f]
```

The first filter that is checked is this one:

```
currency: ['INR']
```

And plan[f] might be 'INR', but it is not ['INR']. So this check will always fail. Therefore the filter returns false and it moves on to the next plan.

What I believe you might be after is something like this:

```js
const plans = [
  {
    amount: 6000,
    currency: "USD",
    frequency: "MONTH",
    planId: "plan_L7mrzVML9o6G5c",
    planName: "computer",
    provider: "stripe",
  },
  {
    amount: 2000,
    currency: "INR",
    frequency: "DAY",
    planId: "plan_KkHkJPEVR7ZA2s",
    planName: "Platinum",
    provider: "stripe",
  },
];

const typeOfFilters = {
  currency: ['INR'],
  frequency: ['DAY'],
  provider: "",
  amount: "",
  status: "",
};

const sortedTableArray = plans.filter(plan => {
  for (const [f, value] of Object.entries(typeOfFilters)) {

    if (value) {
      if (Array.isArray(value) && value.includes(plan[f])) {
        return true;

      } else if (plan[f] === value) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});

console.log(sortedTableArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let plans = [

{
    "amount": 6000,
    "currency": "USD",
    "frequency": "MONTH",
    "planId": "plan_L7mrzVML9o6G5c",
    "planName": "computer",
    "provider": "stripe"
},

{
    "amount": 2000,
    "currency": "INR",
    "frequency": "DAY",
    "planId": "plan_KkHkJPEVR7ZA2s",
    "planName": "Platinum",
    "provider": "stripe"
}
]

 let plansWithId = plans.map((item)=>{
       item.id = guidGenerator();
       return item;
     
 });

const typeOfFilters = {
 
 currency: ['INR'],
  frequency: ['MONTH'],
  provider: "",
  amount: "",
  status: "",
}

// 1. let your typeOfFilters have values are array. If not use typeof to make sure all are in same format.
//2. add a id value to your plans to avoid duplicates


let output = [];
for(key in typeOfFilters){
  let toff = typeOfFilters[key];
  if(typeof(toff) === 'string'){
     toff = [toff];
  }
  const onlyvalues = toff.filter(v => v); // filter empty values
   if(onlyvalues.length){
    temp = plansWithId.filter((item) => {
      return onlyvalues.indexOf(item[key]) !== -1;
    });
    output = output.concat(temp);
   }
}

const selectedIds = [];

const duplicatesRemoved = output.filter((item) => {
  if(selectedIds.indexOf(item.id) !== -1){
  return false;
  }
  selectedIds.push(item.id);
  return true;
})

console.log(duplicatesRemoved)
function guidGenerator() {
    var S4 = function() {
       return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
    };
    return (S4()+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+S4()+S4());
}
```

The approach is difference in this solution. The typeOfFilters are looped first and if it matches with any in plans, the output will be generated.

Note: This is based on OR condition. so any filter matches, it will provide the output.